# PickerView show nothing in text field input

Tags: swift, uipickerview

When I tap on the textField, the input area appear, but there's only 1 row, with blank content. (I expect 3 rows: a,b and c)

I changed the returned value in numberOfRowsInComponent and titleForRow functions to constants, but get the same result (1 blank row). Maybe, these 2 functions never be called.

Please help me!

```
//In ViewDidLoad Function (ViewController.swift):
let myPickerView: MyPickerView = MyPickerView(arrData: ["a","b","c"]){ selected in
     print(selected)
}

textField.inputView = myPickerView.picker





//In MyPickerView.swift
class MyPickerView: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var arrData: Array<String>
    var picker: UIPickerView
    var action: (_ selected: String) -> Void

    public init(
        arrData: Array<String>,
        action: @escaping (_ selected: String) -> Void
        ) {

        self.arrData = arrData
        self.action = action
        self.picker = UIPickerView()

        super.init()

        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self    
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return self.arrData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.action(self.arrData[row])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When I changed myPickerView to global variable (put outside of ViewDidLoad), everything fined.

```
var myPickerView: MyPickerView?

//In ViewDidload
myPickerView = MyPickerView(arrData: ["a","b","c"]){ selected in
     print(selected)
}
```